# Fast way to remove the indices of the main list whose sublist has nan

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python as follows:

```
list_nan = [[1, 2], [nan, nan], [3, 5], [nan, nan], [7, 9]]
```

In the list above, `list_nan[1]` and `list_nan[3]` has `nan` values. How do I get a list as follows:

```
list_clean_nan = [[1, 2], [3, 5], [7, 9]]
```

Thank you for your answwers.

Comment: Where did such a list come from? A `numpy.ndarray`? If it did, it is probably easier to manipulate that `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: @Sujay almost certainly, they mean `float('nan')` not `'nan'`

Comment: In any case, what, exactly, is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: if the nan is a list element, it is quiet simple, but i have to remove the complete sublist of nan from the main list

Comment: So, just iterate over the sublist and check if all the elements are `nan`, no?

Comment: yeah could be! thanks

Comment: in any case, again, if this list comes from a `numpy.array`, you should just work with a pure numpy solution, but if you are not working with numpy, something like `[subl for subl in list_nan if not all(map(math.isnan, subl))]` will work (assuming on if you want to exclude sublists with all nan)

Answer (score 1):

To remove sublists that contains all `NaNs`:

```py
list_nan = [subl for subl in list_nan if not np.all(np.isnan(subl))]
print(list_nan)
```

Print:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [7, 9]]
```

---

EDIT: Solution without `numpy` (thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga):

```py
import math

out = [subl for subl in list_nan if not all(map(math.isnan, subl))]
```

Comment: this, of coures, assumes the OP is working with `numpy`. Might as well add something like `[subl for subl in list_nan if not all(map(math.isnan, subl))]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've added it to my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_clean_nan = [i for i in list_nan if not any(np.isnan(i))]
```

Comment: `something != np.nan` **is not how you can check for `float('nan')`**. By definition, **everything** is `!=` to `nan`, *including `nan`*

Comment: Note, this isn't a "numpy nan". `np.nan` is simply `float('nan')` that is a variable in the `numpy` module scope

Comment: would you agree now @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach for removing lists with `nan` values:

```
import numpy as np

list_nan = [[1, 2], [np.nan, np.nan], [3, 5], [np.nan, np.nan], [7, 9]]
list_nan = [x for x in list_nan if not np.isnan(x).any()]

print(list_nan)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 5], [7, 9]]
```

Comment: this *will not work* in general. This works, *on accident* because you are re-using the *same `float('nan')` object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga An assumption has to be made, otherwise every answer on stackoverflow would be subject to not working in 'general'. It's a valid answer operating under the assumption they are `float('nan')`, which I believe to be a fair assumption in this case.

Comment: No, you don't understand, **this will not work with `float('nan')`**. This **only** works because of a micro-optimization in the implementation of `in` which checks for object identity, and because in your code above you are using `np.nan` (i.e. **the same exact float object**) to construct the lists. Try it with `x = [[1,2,3], [float('nan'), float('nan')]]`

Comment: A *key property* of `float('nan')` is that `float('nan') != float('nan')`. Hence, this *only works* because you did the equivalent of `nan = float('nan')` then `[[1, 2], [nan, nan], [3, 5], [nan,nan], [7, 9]]` and `[x for x in list_nan if nan not in x]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Corrected the answer. Albeit, now mine is much the same as the one above. Better late than never, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't a `numpy` array then convert it first.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(list_nan)
arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=1)].tolist()
>> [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 5.0], [7.0, 9.0]]
```